# Is there a way to send AT commands to an Android phone?

Tags: gsm

Is there a way to send [AT commands](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM7600G-H_4G_DONGLE#Common_AT_Command) to an Android phone (such as via `adb`)?